# Imported Excel file with dates, came out as numbers, trying to return to date format

Tags: r

Based on the structure of the data, I could not import the data by defining the types prior to upload/import.

So, doing that won't work. Anyway, it comes out as a number, below for examples:

43683
43686
43689

I did try some methods. Below is the code I did use and it did sort of end up turning it into a date but the year is wrong (comes out 2089 instead of 2019). I did do trimws prior to the below.

Transactions_Combined$Trans_Date <- as.numeric(Transactions_Comvined$Trans_Date)

Transaction_Combined <- as.Date(Transactions_Combined$Trans_Date)

Comes out as:

'2089-08-07'
'2089-08-10'
'2089-08-13'

Just want an accurate date and make sure I'm doing it right too. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function `readxl::read_excel()` from the `readxl`-package to read in your excel-data.
Set the `col_types`-argument to "Date", and it will read the excel-dates to POSIXct-timestamp.

If this is not an option, you can try

```
as.POSIXct( colum_with_excel_times * 24 * 3600 + as.POSIXct( "1899-12-30 00:00" ) )
```

Comment: Also, if you're using Rstudio, you can use the included GUI function to import the dataset and figure out all the correct settings there: choose the "files" tab in same window as the help and viewer, click on the file you want to import and select import dataset. It will produce the syntax for the call, so it can be reproduced in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! The second part where you pasted the code worked great. I couldn't do the set column types because my original data from the system was set up in a way that two countries data was squished into one Excel sheet separated by columns and totals on top of each other. So I had to create a break and slice. I couldn't do the file path for the same reason as the end goal was to create a refresh button in a visualization software. I really appreciated your code help :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be `janitor::excel_numeric_to_date()`